# ¿Es bueno usar la etiqueta enctype en formularios HTML5?

Tags: html5

Mi pregunta es si es conveniente usarlo o da igual si no lo uso
sin entrar en temas de validación con `PHP` y `JavaScript`

```
<form action="/action_page_binary.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Para ese formulario en concreto no es necesario dicho atributo. se debe usar este valor si se está usando el elemento `<input>` con el atributo `type="file"`

Comment: cuando utilizas `enctype="multipart/form-data"` es requerido cuando utilizas un input de tipo `file`, no es tan necesario si es un formulario donde solo mandas texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario si no vas a usar `input type="file"`

Answer (score 1):

Atributo **enctype** , si es atributo y no etiqueta.

> ¿Es conveniente usarlo o da igual si no lo uso  ?

Es conveniente y absolutamente necesario si su formulario es enviando por método `POST`  y manejará campos de tipo `file` , `<input type="file">` . Si su formulario no cumple con estas **dos** condiciones no es necesario especificarlo . Como su ejemplo no cumple estás dos condiciones no es necesario.

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form) : *Recuerde además Cuando el valor del atributo `method` es `post`, este atributo es el  tipo [MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Lista_completa_de_tipos_MIME) del contenido que es usado para enviar el formulario al servidor.*

Aunque mayormente este atributo es sobreescrito en la etiqueta `form` , puede especificarse en un `botón` o `input`  empleando el atributo `formenctype`

Caso 1

```
<form  action="script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Caso 2

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" >
  <input type="file" name="fichero" >
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar Form" formenctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```